# jq - combining multiple if conditions when keys/values are in different files

Tags: json, if-statement, search, replace, jq

I have two keys in the `license.json` JSON file - `"visitsAnnualQuota"` and `"visitsQuota"` at the very bottom:

```
{
    "customMetricsLimit": 9223372036854776000,
    "customMetricsOverageLimit": 9223372036854776000,
    "UnitsAnnualQuota": 9223372036854776000,
    "UnitsQuota": 9223372036854776000,
    "expirationTime": 1652572799000,
    "infrastructureSupportedTechnologies": {
        "maxInfrastructureOnlyAgents": 9223372036854776000,
        "networkAgent": true,
        "pluginAgent": true
    },
    "logAnalyticsIngressQuota": 9223372036854776000,
    "logAnalyticsIngressQuotaAnnually": 9223372036854776000,
    "maxAgents": 2147483647,
    "maxHostUnitsQuota": -1,
    "maxPaasAgents": 2147483647,
    "maxWebChecks": 9223372036854776000,
    "maxWebChecksAnnual": 9223372036854776000,
    "replayStorageDomQuotaInMb": 9223372036854776000,
    "replayStorageDomRetention": 86400000,
    "retentionCode": 864000000,
    "retentionService": 1209600000,
    "retentionWebcheck": 864000000,
    "symbolicationFileStorageQuota": 1024,
    "syntheticEnabled": true,
    "useHostUnitWeighting": false,
    "visitsAnnualQuota": 120000,
    "visitsQuota": 10000
}
```

I need to set them to value 0 *if* the value of one particular key - `.numberOfVisits` from a *different* `JSON` file - `consumption.json` equals to zero. Here is the fragment of the `consumption.json` file

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Tenant": "Tenant-1"
    },
    "Body": [
        {
            "Metrics": [
                {
                    "timeframe": "Week",
                    "numberOfVisits": 0
                },
                {
                    "timeframe": "Month",
                    "numberOfVisits": 0
                },
                {
                    "timeframe": "Year",
                    "numberOfVisits": 247648006
                }
            ],
            "tags": [
                {
                    "context": "ENVIRONMENT",
                    "key": "srch"
                }
            ],
            "webServerName": "localhost"
        }
    ]
}
```

If the `.numberOfVisits` from `consumption.json` does *not* equal to zero, when `timeframe="Week"` or when `timeframe="Month"` in the same block, then the above two keys need to set to -1 *and* all other keys in the `license.json` file which have the value equal to 9223372036854776000 need to have that value replaced to -1.

What I am doing right now is to have a bash script, read the value of `.numberOfVisits` to a shell variable, and then have a case block for the variable equals or not to zero and for each condition have `jq` called with the appropriate filters.

My question - can all the above logic combined into a single `jq` call?

Comment: It is not clear what levels the keys are nested in both the JSON files. It can be clear only if you add a sample content from both the files

Comment: @Inian - just added a fragment of both files for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done with `jq` in a single shot. All you need to do is use the `--argfile` option on the `consumption.json` and apply the condition on the `numberOfVisits` field

```
jq --argfile visits consumption.json '
    ( $visits | .Body | map( .Metrics[] | select(.numberOfVisits == 0)) | length ) as $data |
    if $data != 2 then
        with_entries( select(.value == 9223372036854776000).value = -1 ) |
          ( .visitsAnnualQuota, .visitsQuota ) |= -1
    elif $data == 2 then
        ( .visitsAnnualQuota, .visitsQuota ) |= 0
    else
        .
    end' license.json
```

The above approach calculates the number of occurrences of `.numberOfVisits` with value 0 and stores in `$data` variable. Then depending on the value in the variable, we apply the filter expressions to modify the fields as required.

Comment: Thanks, good one. One related question - can be ``walk`` applied to the above case? If I want to replace all keys with the name ``.key`` with the specific value, I can use ``'(.. | .key?) |= "abcd"'``. Can the same approach/method used when I need to update all keys based on the value of the key, not the name?

Comment: @Invisible999: Please start a separate thread for subsequent questions.